# SetTimeout is not working in FireFox but fine in IE and wondering why?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code below. Can't understand why it works in IE but not in firefox. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 30000;
    setTimeout(function () {
               window.location.replace = "Index";
    }, delay);

  });
```

Comment: What error you getting in Console?

Comment: Define "not working."

Comment: @Eric , Not working means NOT WORKING , as it should .

Comment: Its not firing/ going to Index page at all. Just sits on the current page. In IE it works as expected

Comment: _Can't understand why it works in IE but not in firefox._...You should check the network tab in firebug if jQuery has been loaded. try clearing the browser cache.

Comment: Change replace to href

Comment: did u try `window.location = href;
return false;`    instead of ur win.loc.replace ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
window.location.replace = "Index";
```

to

```
window.location.replace("Index");
```

use **[replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp)**

```
var delay=30000;
     setTimeout(function () {
                   window.location.replace("Index");
        }, delay);
```

Comment: Then what OP is used differnt?

Comment: This is the same as the question.

Comment: Same code what OP has no improvement just copied something from comment and using here .... not fair

Comment: The OP put window.location.replace = "Index"; the actuall syntax is window.location.replace("Index")

Comment: `window.location.replace("Index");` !== `window.location.replace = "Index";`

Comment: @Sudharsan but the question was why OP's code is not working in FF? and this does not answer that.

Comment: This worked thanks for the help!! Can you provide any reasoning for why the cause of the problem or why is worked?

Comment: You should specify WHAT change u did :) Answer was CORRECT but got downvoted !! +1 frm me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that firefox doesn't like the window.location.replace format.

Try using window.location.href instead

Answer (score 0):

What happens is this:

`window` object's `location` property has a property called `replace`. The content/value of the `replace` property is [a function that replaces the current document with a new one](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp).

You can call this function like this:

```
window.location.replace(<new_url>);
```

But when you do this,

```
window.location.replace = "Index";
```

What happens is, `replace` property's value is changed to (or replaced with) a string, `"Index"`.

Now this is bad. Because `replace` is a utility function that all JavaScript should be able to use.

Firefox does not have a problem. When it creates the anonymous function, it must have detected that you are doing something illegal. So `setTimeout` fails.

But for some strange reason IE seems to allow this for you. Since you are telling us that it's "working in IE", I am curious to know what "working in IE" means. What does IE do? Whatever IE does, it should not do that in this scenario.